# How to manually verify an ECDSA signature in Python?

Tags: signature, python, ecdsa, message-verification

Maybe I got the formula wrong but I heard that `x = (z*s^-1)*G+(r*s^-1)*K` is the equation for verifying an ECDSA signature but my code says signature is invalid but the values are from a valid bitcoin transaction.

```python
def gensig(d,k,h):
    x = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, k)
    r = x[0] % n
    k_inv = mod_inverse(k, n)
    s = (k_inv * (h+(r*d))) % n
    return r,s

def verfy(r,s,pk,h):
    # Verify the signature
    w = mod_inverse(s, n) # Calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of s
    u = (h * w) % n
    v = (r * w) % n
    y = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, u)
    b= bitcoin.fast_multiply(pk, v)
    a = y+b
    x =a[0] % n
    # Check if the calculated point matches the R component of the signature
    if x == r:
        print("Signature is valid")
    else:
        print("Signature is invalid")

def solve_k(h, r, x, s, n):
    # Calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of s modulo n
    s_inverse = mod_inverse(s, n)

    if s_inverse is None:
        return None  # No modular inverse exists

    # Calculate k using the formula
    k = (h + r *x ) * s_inverse % n
    return k

def solve_d(s, k, h, r, n):
    rinv = mod_inverse(r, n)
    d = (((s * k) - h) * rinv) % n
    return d
```

Given these:

```python
R=0x0089848a1c90ee587b1d8b71c9bafccbc072613e41b3fd38cc2b1cf3041e3792bc
S=0x45305be296870b32cca5dac0f0972cac820090214158652581f406fc70ef30f3
Z= 0x3d4a58fa8e5f94e9b8ed1d79a2d584ce45803153b75d43d7bcdbf49171d90992
priv1 = 1
```

When I do this:

```python
pk = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, priv1)
verfy(R,S,pk,Z)
```

I get signature is invalid but why?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the module `bitcoin` you are using? That would be helpful for anyone who wants to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PieterWuille standard bitcoin module, just imported via import bitcoin and pip install

Comment: i think the culprit is y = a+b which should be ECC point addition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected the error was the `+` sign on two points instead point addition is required, so I modified the code like this:

```python
def addp(P,Q):
    point1 = Point(curve, P[0], P[1])
    point2 = Point(curve, Q[0], Q[1])
    # Perform point addition
    result_point = point1 + point2
    return result_point.x()

def dub(Q):
    point1 = Point(curve, Q[0], Q[1])
    # Perform point doubling
    result_point = point1.double()
    return result_point

def verfy(r,s,pk,z):
    # Verify the signature
    w = mod_inverse(s, n) # Calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of s
    u = (z * w) % n
    v = (r * w) % n
    y = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, u)
    b= bitcoin.fast_multiply(pk, v)
    a = addp(y,b)
    x = a % n
    # Check if the calculated point matches the R component of the signature
    if x == r:
        print("Signature is valid")
    else:
        print("Signature is invalid")
```

And it works.